# Base64 Urls safer?

Tags: security, encryption, base64

Are Base64 Urls safer than just regular urls. For example, a rest url like this:
"/user/12?status=true" less safe than "34kalist4u9mF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXRpb24leGNlZWRzIHRo"?

Comment: What do you mean by safe? It's certainly not more secure, since any remotely competent attacker can reverse Base64.

Comment: Assuming you have an english site, base64 is like writing your URL's in Russian.

Comment: This question is better suited for [Security.SE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. Base64 is not an encryption in any way. It is simply an encoding used to represent binary data in ASCII.

If you want your requests to be more secure, use SSL instead.

Answer (score 2):

Shannon's Maxim states "the attacker knows the system", meaning the developer cannot rely on "keyless encryption" (like Base64 which really is not encryption at all) or other mechanisms that are easily broken.

If you want better security consider SSL with strong authentication. You get true encryption with full and correct URLs in the logs and the browser address bar.

Comment: Base64 is by no means an encryption, it’s a simple encoding.

Comment: @Gumbo Exactly why I put it in double quotes. I'll make the answer a bit clearer.